# usage of THE with the plural subject (or noun)

Tags: definite-article, plural-forms, zero-article

I have following construction.

> Table 4 shows the parameters used by the filtering approach. ***The***
>   *parameters* are determined by the knowledge about the data and landscape.

I want to clarify, whether second sentence should be started with THE or without THE. I am confused, as with plural words we are not normally use THE (As I know, is that so?)

Comment: Its absolutely right. But to start with 'Those' will make more sense.

Comment: We can use the definite article with a plural to denote a known or stated subset of the class. Here, the parameters in the table. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10854/rule-on-absence-of-the-article-the-with-plural-nouns

Comment: We do not use "the" with plural nouns? Now I am confused, what do you mean? How do you say a sentence like:"The people in the offices here are all my colleagues." without using "the"? Maybe you meant something else, I am not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confused with *a/an*, which is not used with plurals (it indicates a single but indefinite object). *The* specifies that the noun following it is definite (not just any parameters, but these specific parameters) and is used with singular or plural nouns.

Answer (score 3):

English has three main [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29).

- The [indefinite article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Indefinite_article), used when the following noun refer to an object in a category (or many objects, in the plural), but we don't know which object specifically. The singular form is *a* or *an*, and the plural form is nothing (a [zero article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_article_in_English)).

  > There is **a** car in the street.
  >   There are **{}** cars in the street.
- The [definite article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Definite_article). It is expressed with the word *the* when refering to a specific object (or specific objects, in the plural) which is described by the context.

  > I see a car and a bicycle. **The** car is red.
  >   **The** cars in the street are moving fast.
- A [zero article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article). This is a [partitive article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Partitive_article), and it is also used to refer to general concepts. The partitive article is more commonly singular, but it can be plural; the boundary between a plural partitive article and an indefinite article is not always clear.

  > **{}** Water is wet.

I'm simplifying a lot here — these are just the most common cases.

In this sentence, the subject of the second sentence refers to a specific set of parameters, the ones mentioned in the previous sentence. Therefore the definite article is used. The definite article is always *the*, whether the noun is singular or plural.