# “from Twitter” or “on Twitter”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, definite-article

> Below are recent tweets **from/on** Twitter.

1. Should I use **from** or **on**?
2. Should I use **recent tweets** or **the recent tweets**?

Comment: I'd say either depending on context. So if you try and include "from"/"on" in complete sentences we will be able to comment on your proposals.  There are two questions. The use the definite article "the" has often been dealt with here, maybe this [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/11333/2818). If not I'd suggest you just ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are okay but then if we get into subtlety, *from twitter* gives me an idea that Twitter itself sent you some messages. *I received something from something/someone*.

On the other hand, latest tweets on Twitter sounds okay as it tells that you found those messages on Twitter recently.

Now, the *article* issue. Articles are always tough (at least for me!) but then here, *the recent tweets* shall work as you are specific about the (identified) recent messages.

Comment: I'd say that we don't need the article, and probably shouldn't use it unless we've alluded to the tweets somewhere previously. For example, _"Below are recent tweets from Twitter"_ is just fine on its own. But consider this context: _"The Twittersphere has gotten particularly nasty for Richie Incognito. He sent a barrage of messages in a single night. Below are **the** recent tweets."_ In this case, we keep the article, to show that the tweets listed below are the ones referenced in the previous sentence.

Comment: That's why I wrote that those tweets are *identified* as *the* latest tweets

Comment: Yes, you did, but I thought this answer could profit from a more concrete example, so I added one in my comment.